# Semantics: Does the order of writing quantifiers matter?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there a difference (in meaning) between the two sentences:

$ \exists K \in \mathbb{N} \mid  0 \le a_k \le  b_k, \forall ( k \ge K)$

$ \exists K \in \mathbb{N}, \forall ( k \ge K)\mid  0 \le a_k \le  b_k$

The correct English sentence I want to translate is "Suppose there is an index K such that$ 0 \le a_k \le  b_k$ for all $ k \ge K$"

This sentence was taken from here: http://persweb.wabash.edu/facstaff/footer/Courses/M111-112/Handouts/SERIES1.PDF

Trying to avoid plagiarism

Comment: Quantifiers are traditionally placed at the beginning of the formula they scope over. So the first one looks kind of weird.

Comment: In general, order matters: $\forall \exists$ is **not** the same as $\exists \forall$: well-known counter-examples are easy to manufacture with $<$.

Comment: In this case, the sentence is $\exists K \forall k \ge K \ldots$

Comment: The first version is syntactically unconventional. It is ambiguous since someone trying to translate it into a comprehensible form could come up with either "there exists K such that for all k..." or "for all k there exist K such that...". In this case semantic considerations would demand the first interpretation, but it is always bad practice to write something ambiguous and rely on the reader working out that one of the two meanings is nonsense.

Comment: Of course order of quantifier matters. The problem with the first example is, nobody can be sure what order is intended: does '|' or ',' have higher precedence? Neither is a part of the language of standard first order logic. I don't know how to parse it. My only advice is: don't write this way.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA why did you exclude the part where K is not in the natural numbers?

To others: Thank you for the explanation.  I understand now.